# webpack-component using babel loader

Tags: webpack

How can I load webpack-components using component plugin using a babel loader .

My Webpack-config.json looks like this :

```
var ComponentPlugin = require("component-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
entry: "./entry.js",
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "[name].js"
},
 resolve: {
    extensions: [ '', '.js', '.css' ]
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel' },
       { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ComponentPlugin({
        // This is equal to: xyz: "[file]"

        // Load xyz field with the xyz-loader
         scripts: "!babel-loader![file]"

    }, [
        // Lookup paths 
        "components"
    ])
]
};
```

But still when I use require('react') in my  component js file its throwing me parse error.

Comment: error output, please.

Comment: ERROR in ./components/a-component/index.js
Module not found: /home/y/share/htdocs/UIworkspace/PI-UI-React-POC/components/a-component/component.json parsing failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected string
 @ ./components/a-component/index.js 3:12-28

Comment: var React = require('react');
    var YourName ="hello";
    module.exports = YourName;